# advanced grouping and aggregation with linq

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

I have the program below:

```
 void Main()
{



List<Online_video_for_programmers> current_year_videos = new List<Online_video_for_programmers>()
    {
    new Online_video_for_programmers
        {
        video_name="websocket for fortran programmers",
        season=2,
        seasontype=1,
        year=2012
        },
        new Online_video_for_programmers
        {
        video_name="cross site scripting for facebook addicts",
        season=3,
        seasontype=2,
        year=2012
        },

        new Online_video_for_programmers
        {
        video_name="Artificial intelligence for self aware robots",
        season=1,
        seasontype=1,
        year=2012
        }
        ,
        new Online_video_for_programmers
        {
        video_name="Artificial intelligence for self aware robots",
        season=3,
        seasontype=1,
        year=2012
        },

        new Online_video_for_programmers
        {
        video_name="Artificial intelligence for adavanced robots",
        season=5,
        seasontype=1,
        year=2012
        },
    new Online_video_for_programmers
        {
        video_name="Yoga for programmers",
        season=2,
        seasontype=2,
        year=2012
        },
        new Online_video_for_programmers
        {
        video_name="Yoga for programmers",
        season=3,
        seasontype=2,
        year=2012
        }


    };

    //Last years videos sold

List<Online_video_for_programmers> last_year_videos = new List<Online_video_for_programmers>()
    {
    new Online_video_for_programmers
        {
        video_name="websocket for fortran programmers",
        season=2,
        seasontype=1,
        year=2011,
        },
        new Online_video_for_programmers
        {
        video_name="cross site scripting for facebook addicts",
        season=3,
        seasontype=1,
        year=2011,
        },

        new Online_video_for_programmers
        {
        video_name="Artificial intelligence for self aware robots",
        season=2011,
        seasontype=3,
        year=2011,
        }
        ,

    new Online_video_for_programmers
        {
        video_name="Yoga for programmers",
        season=4,
        seasontype=2,
        year=2011,
        },
            new Online_video_for_programmers
        {
        video_name="Yoga for programmers",
        season=2,
        seasontype=2,
        year=2011
        }

};
}
// Define other methods and classes here





 public class Online_video_for_programmers
    {
    public int seasontype {get;set;} //this can be the id of a year, a quater or  month  Tyepes are 1: months, 2, for quarters, 3 for year
public int season {get;set;} //  when season type is 1, season =1 means january. 
    //When season type is 2, season=3 means 3rd quater. When seasontype is 3, season =2011 or 2010 etc... 
        public string video_name {get;set;} //The nambe of the video
        public int year {get;set;} // The year the video was published
}
```

I would like to use current_year_videos and last_year_videos to retreive what titles where published last year and not this year. For this i use the following code:

```
var result=current_year_videos.Concat(last_year_videos).GroupBy( g=> new { seasontype,season,video_name }).Select(s=> new Online_video_for_programmers{  seasontype=s.Key.seasontype, season=s.Key.season, video_name=s.Key.video_name });
```

The code above gives me the ones that were produced both this year and last year, so that i can easily find the missing ones.

And here is the problem. The video "Artificial intelligence for self aware robot" was produced for the entire year in 2011 while there were 3 monthly productions in 2012. 
I do not want to see this as missing for 2012. It should only be missing if it was not produced at all in 2012. The question is, how to adjust my query to include this condition in the result.
I spent some time figuring different things with no success so far.

Hope someone can help.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var result = 
    last_year_videos
       .Select(v => new { v.video_name, v.season })
       .Except(current_year_videos.Select(v => new { v.video_name, v.season }));
```

Gives:

```
{ video_name = "Artificial intelligence for self aware robots", season = 2011 }
{ video_name = "Yoga for programmers", season = 4 }
```

UPDATE: If you want to deal with season type (month, quarter, year) when checking videos, then you can create method which converts season and season type to list of months:

```
private static IEnumerable<int> GetMonths(Online_video_for_programmers video)
{
    switch (video.seasontype)
    {
        case 1: return Enumerable.Range(video.season, 1);
        case 2: return Enumerable.Range((video.season - 1) * 3 + 1, 3);
        case 3: return Enumerable.Range(1, 12);
        default:
            throw new ArgumentException("Unknown season type");
    }
}
```

With this method you can check if video has months intersections with same video from current year:

```
var currentVideos = 
    current_year_videos.Select(c => new { c.video_name, months = GetMonths(c) });

var result = from v in last_year_videos
             let months = GetMonths(v)
             where !currentVideos.Any(cv => 
                       cv.video_name == v.video_name &&
                       months.Intersect(cv.months).Any())
             select v.video_name;
```

Returns:

```
"cross site scripting for facebook addicts" // Month 3
"Yoga for programmers" // Months 9,10,11
```

Comment: Dear Lazyberezovsky, there is an issue with this code. It should not report "Artificial intelligence for self aware robots" as missing. It was produced in 2011. It should only be reported as missing if it was not produced at all.

Comment: @MeelfanBmfp nope, in 2012 it has seasons `1,3,5`. But in 2011 was season named `2011` thus it is different video, and it is displayed in results. Maybe you have typo in your sample data?

Comment: No, i have not explained it that well. If we find data for the whole year in one end and in any other form in the other end, then it is considered as not missing. "Artificial intelligence for self aware robots" was produced once in 2011 for the entire year. in 2012, it was produced on a monthly basis. So here we can assume that it is not missing. I hope this makes sence.

Comment: "Artificial intelligence for self aware robots" is produced in 2011 and that is the entire year that cover any month or any quarter. This film is therefor not missing from that year. If it was produce say: January and April for 2011 and May, June for 2012, then we would flag May, June as missing for 2011 since the film was not produced in these months. In turn, if in 2011, it was produced in 2 quarter(this include May and June), then these production woukd not be flagged as missing. we have 2nd quarter for 2011 and May and June

Comment: May and June are part of the 2nd quarter so these productions are not missing. I know it sound complicated but this is why i'm having a hard time finding a simple solution.

Comment: @MeelfanBmfp sorry, didn't get your logic. If movie was produced on May 2011 and June 2012, then it should be included, but if it was produced on second quarter of 2011, and June 2012, then it should not be included?

Comment: exactly! Your code and idea is fantastic and you are a true genius. I never though of the conversion idea. Thousands thanks

Answer (score 0):

You want to find:

> *what titles where published last year and not this year*

but for that, there is no need for grouping:

```
var result = last_year_videos
    .Where(vLast => !current_year_videos
        .Select(vCurrent => vCurrent.video_name).Contains(vLast.video_name));
```

All you have to do is to check if the video with the selected key (`video_name`) exists in the last year's collection.

Comment: Check names. All exist in the last year's collection

Comment: I agree. In spite of that, to my understanding, this is the solution to the problem.

Comment: Even if you will replace video_name with anonymous object, your query is very inefficient - it does projection of current year videos and executes search for *every* video in list year list.